# Top 1 not returning results when joined

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below SQL query that is attempting to return the Last Transaction date for a specific part. The subquery that I'm left joining runs fine when I run it by itself (with the part specific criteria)

```
SELECT TOP 1 S1.* 
FROM PartTran S1 
WHERE S1.TranDate > '10/10/2016' AND S1.TranType <> 'ADJ-CST' AND S1.PartNum = '0000AAAO' ORDER BY S1.TranDate DESC
```

[image]

However when I join this into my main query, its returning null.

```
SELECT T1.PartNum, T2.TranDate, T2.TranType
FROM dbo.Part T1 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 S1.* FROM PartTran S1 WHERE S1.TranDate > '10/10/2016' AND S1.TranType <> 'ADJ-CST' ORDER BY S1.TranDate DESC) T2 ON T1.Company = T2.Company AND T1.PartNum = T2.PartNum
WHERE T1.PartNum = '0000AAAO'
```

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's cristal clear that your top 1 record doesn't not have a match with T1 by `Company` and `PartNum`. Why don't you check this point?

Comment: In this software, `Company` is a integral field that exists in every table, and it is also impossible to have a Part Transaction without Part that exists. Parts cannot be deleted. Only in-actived. So its crystal clear that this was solid.

Comment: As I said. It is cristal clear that whether you join 2 tables and you get no results, is because your datasets don't match.

Comment: @Pants You don't want a left join here.. you want a cross apply to get the top 1 of each record.

Comment: @JaimeDrq at the point of testing I didn't understand the issue. Thanks to xQbert and mkRabbani for the guidance to understanding my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check this following query-

```
SELECT 
T1.PartNum, 
       T2.TranDate, 
       T2.TranType
FROM dbo.Part T1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 S1.*
    FROM PartTran S1
    WHERE S1.TranDate > '10/10/2016'
          AND S1.TranType <> 'ADJ-CST'
          AND S1.PartNum = '0000AAAO' 
          -- I think this above filter (AND S1.PartNum = '0000AAAO') is required 
          -- other wise top 1 can select records belongs to other PartNum  and
          -- your left join will return NULL logically
    ORDER BY S1.TranDate DESC
) T2 ON T1.Company = T2.Company
        AND T1.PartNum = T2.PartNum
WHERE T1.PartNum = '0000AAAO';
```

Comment: This fixed it. Originally in my query it was an inner join, however i wasn't getting anything so i changed it to a left to see what was going on. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome. Nice to see that its helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your original query doesn't work has to do with order of operations.

The derived table T2 resulted in 1 and only 1 record; not 1 record per PART number.  This has to do with the derived table obtaining it's results BEFORE it can be joined to T1.  Since the part numbers didn't match unless you got lucky on the part and day and company... you would get no data.  A cross/outer apply allows you to get the TOP record per Join Criteria. and thus will return multiple records; 1 for each part and company; instead of just 1.

I think you're after a cross or outer apply and you can avoid the 2nd filter in the derived table (T2)  If you want parts w/o any transactions kept then use the outer apply, if you only want those with part transactions use cross apply.

```
SELECT T1.PartNum, T2.TranDate, T2.TranType
FROM dbo.Part T1 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 S1.* 
             FROM PartTran S1 
             WHERE S1.TranDate > '10/10/2016' 
               AND S1.TranType <> 'ADJ-CST' 
             ORDER BY S1.TranDate DESC) T2 
  ON T1.Company = T2.Company 
 AND T1.PartNum = T2.PartNum
WHERE T1.PartNum = '0000AAAO'
```

Alternatively you could use a row number instead of top and partition by your company and partNum ordering by transdate and only return row number 1st ordering by your transdate descending.

Here's a [MSDN Doc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/796821b0-ba48-49b4-ba42-1783061d8c41/cross-apply-in-sqlserver?forum=transactsql)  link showing how cross/outer apply 
works.

Comment: So does this basically `CROSS APPLY` any criteria placed in the main query, to whatever table/subquery I `CROSS APPLY` to? Never used this

Comment: The difference between the join and APPLY operator becomes evident when you have a table-valued expression on the right side and you want this table-valued expression to be evaluated for each row from the left table expression.  In this case we want to find the TOP 1 record for each record in parts.  Give it a whirl.  Note that you no longer need the teh partNum filter on the inner query.   And now if you just want a list of all of the parts and the most recent partTrans. it's done in 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'LEFT' in your join because it is allowing you to select rows in the sub query that don't meet the criteria of your WHERE clause. That seemed to fix the issue in my text environment at least.

Comment: The Left Join was simply used to show that data was coming back, but i was receiving null results, when in my example the subquery being ran would return records. In my actual query i was using inner

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.PartNum, T.TranDate, T.TranType
FROM dbo.Part p JOIN
     PartTran pt
      ON pt.Company = p.Company AND
         pt.PartNum = t.PartNum AND
         pt.TranType <> 'ADJ-CST' AND
         pt.TranDate > '2016-10-10'
WHERE p.PartNum = '0000AAAO'
ORDER BY pt.TranDate DESC;
```

Comment: For testing purposes, the where criteria for the PartNum was added to shorten query execution time. In the actualy use this will be removed. Therefore requiring the Top 1 to be contained within a subquery. However thanks for the answer

Comment: @Pants . . . I'm not sure I agree.  You either want the most recent row according to some conditions or you do not.